# Serializing custom model fields in TokenObtainPairSerializer

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

Im using djangorestframework-simplejwt. I want to make TokenObtainPairView take in `first_name`, `last_name`, `phone_number` and `email` to authenticate instead of the default username and password, so that I can instead make a `/register` endpoint that will both register and login in a single request. (For reference this is the urlpattern typically used with `TokenObtainPairView` typically

```py
path('api/token/', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

I've been able to make this work with writing normal serializer fields like below

```py
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    
    first_name = serializers.CharField()
    last_name = serializers.CharField()
    email = serializers.EmailField()

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Is there a way to use ModelSerializer to do this instead? e.g something like this (the below doesn't work)

```py
class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer, ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

Comment: So, whats the question/issue here?

Comment: @JPG I'v edited the question. So my question is, is there a way to use ModelSerializer instead of manually defining the serializer fields, e.g something like the code snippet at the bottom of my post